# how to know if I'm decorating a method

Tags: python, python-2.7

It seems that mymethod is not yet a method when the decorator is called.

```
import inspect

class decorator(object):
    def __call__(self, call):
        if inspect.ismethod(call): #Not working yet
            obj = "method"
            args = inspect.getargspec(call)[0][1:]
        elif inspect.isfunction(call):
            obj = "function"
            args = inspect.getargspec(call)[0]
        elif inspect.isclass(call):
            obj = "class"
            args = inspect.getargspec(call.__init__)[0][1:]

        args="(%s)" % repr(args)[1:-1].replace("'","")
        print "Decorate %s %s%s" % (obj, call.__name__, args)
        return call


@decorator()
def myfunction (a,b): pass

@decorator()
class myclass():
    def __init__(self, a, b): pass

    @decorator()
    def mymethod(self, a, b): pass

if inspect.isfunction(myclass.mymethod):
    print "mymethod is a function"
if inspect.ismethod(myclass.mymethod):
    print "mymethod is a method"
```

Output:

```
Decorate function myfunction(a, b)
Decorate function mymethod(self, a, b)
Decorate class myclass(a, b)
mymethod is a method
```

I would know if the first argument is 'self', but there will be a less dirty solution?

Edit: **Why?**

I want to populate a list of callables and their arguments, if it is a function or a class, and I can pass the expected arguments, then I call it, but if it is a method, I have no "self" argument to pass. Something like:

```
import inspect

class ToDo(object):
    calls=[]

    def do(self, **kwargs):
        for call in self.calls:
            if 'self' in call.args:
                print "This will fail."
            args = {}
            for arg in call.args:
                args[arg]=kwargs.get(arg, None)
            call.call(**args)

TODO = ToDo()

class decorator(object):
    def __call__(self, call):
        if inspect.isfunction(call):
            args = inspect.getargspec(call)[0]
        elif inspect.isclass(call):
            args = inspect.getargspec(call.__init__)[0][1:]

        self.call = call
        self.args = args
        TODO.calls.append(self)
        return call

TODO.do(a=1, b=2)
```

Comment: Why do you need to know to begin with? For most purposes, a method is just another callable and can be decorated exactly like a non-method function.

Comment: Agreed, there is no good answer to this without knowing why you need to know. In general, if it *really* needs to be different, maybe you should be using a different decorator for each case.

Comment: Don't change your decorator implicitly based on whether or not you are dealing with a class method or a function. It's the opposite of pythonic. make your decorator do the same thing regardless (if you **really** need this form of magic, try explaining ***what*** you are doing!)

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I want to know because I will not allow decorated methods. The decorator does one thing if a class, another if it is a function, and I want to throw an exception if you try to decorate a method.

Comment: However, this is still a bad idea. not allowing decorated methods? why? and to reiterate and further home the point, why? why would you ever consider distinguishing two callables and refusing to do the same thing? let the user decide: be *explicit*. If the user decorates a callable, decorate it. throwing an exception solely because a callable is decorated is unexpected behaviour and will result in users scratching their heads at you.

Comment: A function with a first argument of `self` is no guarantee that the function is an instance method. There doesn't seem to be any guaranteed way of making the distinction solely by using a decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really make that distinction. Here's an example:

```
>>> class A(object):
...    pass
...
>>> def foo(x): return 3
...
>>> A.foo = foo
>>> type(foo)
<type 'function'>
>>> type(A.foo)
<type 'instancemethod'>
```

As you can see, your decorator could apply to `foo`, since it is a function. But you can then simply create a class attribute that references the function to create a decorated method.

(This example is from Python 2.7; I'm not sure if anything has changed in Python 3 to make the above behave differently.)

Comment: This has indeed changed in Python 3. `type(foo) is type(A.foo)`, though `A().foo` still gives a bound method for obvious reasons.

Comment: Understood, at that scope still is a function, because not yet been assigned as class method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell method from function but you can check if first argument looks like self:

```
def __call__(self, func):
    def new_func(*args, **kw):
        if len(args) and hasattr(args[0], '__dict__') \
                and '__class__' in dir(args[0]) and func.__name__ in dir(args[0])\
                and '__func__' in dir(getattr(args[0], func.__name__))\
                and getattr(args[0], func.__name__).__func__ == self.func:
            return my_func(*args[1:], **kw)
        else:
            return my_func(*args, **kw)

    self.func = new_func
    return new_func
```

But that won't work for nested decorators - next decorator will change the function and comparison with self.func won't work.

Another approach - to check if first argument's name of decorated function is self - this is
very strong convention in Python so may be good enough:

```
def __call__(self, func):
    def new_func(*args, **kw):
        if len(inspect.getfullargspec(func).args)\
           and inspect.getfullargspec(func).args[0] == 'self':
            return my_func(*args[1:], **kw)
        else:
            return my_func(*args, **kw)

    self.func = new_func
    return new_func
```